# Proper English for "started shooting anywhere"

Tags: single-word-requests, adverbs

What's the proper word to describe someone shooting anywhere around in order to kill as many as possible:

> The terrorists entered the room and started shooting ***_*__*_*__*_*_**, 5 were killed, 1 injured.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Indiscriminately

is a word for acting without control or precision. To discriminate is to choose*, so something indiscriminate is without the choosing. In your case, if they'd fired without choosing targets, this would be a good word.

*Since the Civil Rights movement it's had a connotation for choosing for bad reasons.

> Maliciously

Malice is intentional, almost *gleeful* evil. Shooting with the intent to kill lots of bystanders is without a doubt malicious.

> Into the crowd

while a phrase, not a word, it seems to be a straightforward description of what they did.

> To kill

Another phrase, but "shooting to kill" is an expression for trying to use a weapon to commit murder, as opposed to using it to intimidate or suppress. It also has action-movie sensibilities, so it conveys the ... *action* implied by your explanation.

Comment: Indiscriminately it is.

Answer (score 3):

*Anywhere* isn't the right word. It might suffice to say **everywhere**, but you'd probably need to make it more specific, e.g., ** in every direction** to indicate that they weren't interested in specific targets but only in killing as many people as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Although I think I'm with rsegal and *indiscriminately* (and have upvoted his answer) another option might be *in all directions*.

> The terrorists entered the room and started shooting **in all directions**.

Comment: I'd say randomly.

Answer (score 1):

Indiscriminately sounds to me more determined, so perhaps that is the better word but the word *wildly* is often used in this context.

> The terrorists entered the room and started shooting wildly, 5 were killed, 1 injured